# wkhtmltopdf shows & B I G S T A R ; instead of (star)

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

generate a PDF using **wkhtmltopdf** library.

After generate pdf it shows & B I G S T A R ; instead of (star)

```
    On live server Side
```

[image]
and in view source it show like &bigstar
[image]

```
   on local server
```

it show star on pdf...
[image]

but on live server it not show stars. how to resolve it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE **&#9734**(and Add ; in last) instead of **&BIGSTAR;**

After that it show like **☆**